# Find Laplace transform of $f(t)=\sin^2 t$ using $\mathcal{L}(\frac{d}{dt}f(t))=\mathcal{L}(f'(t))$. (Check my answer)

Tags: solution-verification, laplace-transform

I want to find Laplace transform of $f(t)=\sin^2 t$ using $\mathcal{L}(\dfrac{d}{dt}f(t))=\mathcal{L}(f'(t))$.

This is my answer.

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&& \mathcal{L} (f'(t)) &= \mathcal{L} (\sin(2t))\\
\iff& & sF(s)-f(0)&= \frac{2}{s^2+4}\\
\iff& & sF(s)-0&= \frac{2}{s^2+4}\\
\iff& & F(s)&= \frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}.
\end{alignat*}

and we have
$$F(s)=\mathcal{L} \left(\sin^2 t\right)=\dfrac{2}{s(s^2+4)}.$$

Is this right or wrong answer?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. (For what it's worth, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Laplace+transform+of+sin%5E2%28t%29) also happens to agree.) Good job!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The OP's question was whether this was correct or not, and I see nothing further to comment on. Better to have an answer like this, than to leave the question in the unanswered queue.